# Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found. Not good.'

Tags: php, dompdf

estou tendo um problema na geração de um arquivo pdf a partir de uma string html.

o erro informado é o seguinte:

```
Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found. Not good.'
```

O código para geração do pdf segue abaixo:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(stripslashes($html));
$dompdf->set_paper("a4");
$dompdf->render();
$out = $dompdf->output();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja tive este problema no passado e este código salvou meu dia.
Tente verificar se há espaços entre as TAGS HTML.
Tente usar este código, ele retira qualquer espaço entre as TAGS

```
$html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html);
```

antes da linha `$dompdf->load_html(stripslashes($html));`